# Calculate the pixel location of an object in the rendered result

Tags: python, camera, transforms, coordinates

I'm implementing a simple script to calculate the location of an object (which is a 2D plane) in the rendered image:

```
import bpy
import bpy_extras

context = bpy.context
scene = context.scene

camera = scene.camera
render = scene.render

def image_location_of(object):
    width = render.resolution_x * render.resolution_percentage / 100.0
    height = render.resolution_y * render.resolution_percentage / 100.0

    projected_location = bpy_extras.object_utils.world_to_camera_view(
        scene=scene,
        obj=camera,
        coord=object.location
    )

    return (
        projected_location.x * width,
        projected_location.y * height
    )
```

Basically, the script calls `world_to_camera_view` to convert the global location of the object (i.e. `object.location`) to the location under the camera's view, then scales this location with the width and the height of the image.

Unfortunately, the returned (x,y) is very wrong (in many times it is even bigger than the size of the image). Did I do anything wrong?

Comment: Hello ! Are you sure the object's origin is located in the view frustum of the camera ?

Comment: Thank you.
Yes, I'm sure. I've implemented a piece of code to move the object to the view frustum (if it wasn't), and I can even observe that the object appears in the rendered image.

Comment: The object might appear in the rendered image but its origin might be far from its geometry. Here you are testing the object location which is its origin

Comment: Cmon bro, there is node which gives you position in window space  its called "texture coordinate". And you can get position for every vertex of mesh. But its limited to shading editor. So maybe im actually wrong